# Limit to one tag in Angular

Tags: support, feature-request, tags

I'm an active user in the Angular scenario, and every day it happens that people put both [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) and [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) tag in their question.

To me it is really boring, and for now I just edit the question, removing the wrong tag.

I was wondering: is it possible to limit, in this case, the user to just be able to put either [angluar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angluar) or [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) as a tag?

Comment: Blocking shouldn't be done because there might be legitimate questions using both tags, but a warning message could prove useful.

Comment: Mine was just an idea. You are anyway right. Maybe prevent the user in this way isn't the best approch.

Comment: This has been [discussed several times](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=angular). My position has been to not distinguish between -js and non -js.

Comment: To me would make sense to distinguish between -js and non -js.

Comment: @Braiam they are totally different frameworks. Differentiation is a necessity.

Comment: @DavidWalschots there has been many times where SO didn't follow the product naming schemes of companies if it didn't make sense. This is one of the cases where it doesn't make sense.

Comment: For real? I personally don't know anything about angularJS, so if your suggest get approved I have to manually check one-for-one question just to know if the user is asking something about -js or non -js? No-sense at all.

Comment: What is *"the Angular scenario"*? Can you elaborate?